# How hard is it to compute the Davenport constant?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, additive-combinatorics

The [Davenport constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport_constant) $D(G)$ of a finite abelian group $(G,+)$ is the least positive integer $k$ such that every sequence in $G$ of length $k$ has a zero-sum (nonempty) subsequence.

It seems that the Davenport constant is explicitly known only in a handful of cases (such as when $G$ is cyclic, or is a $p$-group, or has rank $2$). Is anything known about how hard it is to compute the Davenport constant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Davenport constants for all groups of order less than thirty-two is computed in [arXiv.1702.02997](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1702.02997), using GAP. The algorithm is presented and the complexity is discussed in section 6. The run-time varies by orders of magnitude from one group to another, dependent on the number of equivalence classes that need to be considered.